# Why does changes in load factor affect the stalling speed?

Tags: stall, weight-and-balance, student-pilot

Why does changes in load factor affect the stalling speed?

Is it because with an increase of load, the airplane has to fly at a faster airspeed to maintain performance because of the weight it has to carry.

Comment: Does this answer your question (duplicate)? [Why does a higher load factor increase stall speed?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/74061/why-does-a-higher-load-factor-increase-stall-speed)